# How to use Group by query in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, join, group-by

[this is how the data is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo0fv.jpg) but i want

> Rhugveda desai -> flowers,Sarees,Prasad

In my application i need to use group by clause . But i am getting a syntax error.Also, What should i do if i want quantity column to be multiplied by amount to get the total? My tables are inkind and inkind_items, where inkind.id is foreign key in inkind_items table as inkind_id.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #11
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column

my inkind_items tabel is [inkind_items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye22u.jpg)
my inkind table is [inkind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa41h.jpg)
My query is:

```
$inkinds = DB::table('inkind')
     ->join('inkind_items', 'inkind.id', '=', 'inkind_items.inkind_id')
     ->select('inkind.*', 'inkind_items.*')
     ->groupBy('inkind_items.inkind_id')
     ->get();
```

Comment: In ->select('inkind.*', 'inkind_items.*') you must have to specify the columns. You can't left this with * if there is more then one fields need to fetch, then you have to specify rest of the fields in group by clause.

Comment: @VikashPathak Can you please elaborate?

Comment: in select statement try specify single field only instead of *.. does this work?

Comment: Can you please check the updated question? @VikashPathak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `group_concat()`

```
$inkinds = DB::table('inkind')
     ->join('inkind_items', 'inkind.id', '=', 'inkind_items.inkind_id')
     ->select('inkind.*', DB::raw('group_concat(inkind_items.name) as items'))
     ->groupBy('inkind_items.inkind_id')
     ->get();
```

Here I'm assuming `inkind` have field `name` and `inkind_items` has fields `items`.

Comment: Does this helpful?

Comment: Nope does'nt give answer as required. i have uploaded my table data

Comment: @RhugvedaDesai try now.. updated the solution. Let me know if you are still getting the issue.

Comment: Updated solution now.. @RhugvedaDesai included `*`

Comment: One more query! What should i do if i want quantity column to be multiplied by amount to get the total?

Comment: Just add `inkind_items.quantity * inkind_items.amount as total` with  `->select()` like    `->select('inkind.*', DB::raw('group_concat(inkind_items.name) as items'), DB::raw('inkind_items.quantity * inkind_items.amount as total'))`

Comment: i tried it ! but getting this error-> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #7 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'manmandir.inkind_items.quantity' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; –

Comment: you can't add more columns if these are not in group by.. why not you are adding another query for the these total calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel collection methods for that.

Just call:

```
$inkinds->groupBy('inkind_id');
```

after ->get(). Considering that inkind_id is unique column for both tables

Answer (score 1):

**Hi. You asked another question earlier today** (about displaying an input when a particular checkbox is checked) **but deleted it before I submitted my answer, so I thought I would paste the answer here instead:**

> Just to get you started, here is an explanation of how to use
>   `addEventListener` and `createElement` to achieve your desired result.
>
> If any part of it is still unclear after studying the code and the
>   accompanying comments, please search for the name of the still-unclear function on
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference).
>   (For example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName.)

```js
// Sets `box1` to refer to the first element on the page with the class "box".
const box1 = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];

// Sets `container` to be the element whose id attribute has the value "container".
//   (This is where our new input element, inside a new label element, will be added.)
const container = document.getElementById("container");

// Begins listening for clicks. From now on, whenever the user clicks anywhere
//   on the page, our listener will call the `noticeClick` function.
document.addEventListener("click", noticeClick);

function noticeClick(event){
  // Because this function's name is the second argument in 
  //   the call to `document.addEventListener`, above, it is
  //   automatically called every time a 'click' event happens on the 
  //   page (and it automatically receives that event as an argument.)
  // The "target" of the event is whatever the user clicked on.

  // So we set the variable `targ` to refer to this target, and we check whether:
  //   1) the clicked target is our checkbox,
  //   2) this click caused the checkbox to gain the "checked" attribute, and
  //   3) we have not already given the checkbox the "added" class
  const targ = event.target;
  if(targ.id == "box1" && targ.checked && !targ.classList.contains("added")){

  // If all three conditions are met, we...
    // ...set two variables, `label` and `val`
    const label = event.target.id;
    const val = event.target.value;

    // ...call the `createInput` function, passing these variables as its two arguments
    createInput(label, val);

    // ...give the checkbox the "added" class (so we can avoid accidentally adding it again)
    targ.classList.add("added");
  }
}

function createInput(newLabel, newValue){
  // When the user has checked our checkbox, the `noticeClick` function
  //   will call this function, which receives two arguments (which we can   
  //   see, by examining the `noticeClick` function, are two strings: the  
  //   `id` attribute of box1 and the `value` attribute of box1.)
  
  // We use `document.creatElement` to create an `input` element and a 
  //   `label` element, and `document.createTextNode` to set some text 
  //   to be used in the label (using the "newLabel" argument.)
  const myInput = document.createElement("input");
  const myLabel = document.createElement("label");
  const myLabelText = document.createTextNode(newLabel + " ");

  // We set our new `input` element's value using the "newValue" argument.
  myInput.value = newValue;

  // We use `appendChild` to put both the text and the input element
  //   inside the label, and to put the label inside `container`.
  myLabel.appendChild(myLabelText);
  myLabel.appendChild(myInput);
  container.appendChild(myLabel);
}


// This process can be applied to multiple checkboxes on the same page 
//   by adding a loop inside the `noticeClick` function, where the string
//   "box1" should be replaced with a variable that can refer to the id of a
//   different checkbox's `id` for each iteration of the loop.
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="box1" class="box" value="value1" />
  Label for box1
</label>
<hr />
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Hello @Cat Thank you very much for replying !! i have some difficulties. I''ll upload a question about it .